# Extract numbers after a pattern in vector of characters

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm trying to extract values from a vector of strings. Each string in the vector, (there are about 2300 in the vector), follows the pattern of the example below:

```
"733|Overall (-2 to 2): _________2________________|How controversial is each sentence (1-5)?|Sent. 1 (ANALYSIS BY...): ________1__________|Sent. 2 (Bail is...): ____3______________|Sent. 3 (2) A...): _______1___________|Sent. 4 (3) A...): _______1___________|Sent. 5 (Proposition 100...): _______5___________|Sent. 6 (In 2006,...): _______3___________|Sent. 7 (That legislation...): ________1__________|Types of bias (check all that apply):|Pro   Anti|X      O   Word use (bold, add alternate)|X      O   Examples (italicize)|O      O   Extra information (underline)|X      O   Any other bias (explain below)|Last sentence makes it sound like an urgent matter.|____________________________________________|NA|undocumented, without a visa|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|"
```

What I'd like is to extract the numbers following the pattern "Sent. " and place them into a separate vector. For the example, I'd like to extract "1311531".

I'm having trouble using `gsub` to accomplish this.

Comment: Are al the numbers **ALWAYS** integers between 0 and 9?

Comment: @OrlandoSabogal: Yes they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_match_all` from `stringr` to get all the numbers followed by `"Sent"`.

```
str_match_all(text, "Sent.*?_+(\\d+)")[[1]][, 2]
#[1] "1" "3" "1" "1" "5" "3" "1"
```

Comment: This worked very well and very fast. Do you have a suggestion about how to make it run over a vector of strings besides a for-loop?

Comment: @StanO `str_match_all` is already vectorised. So if you have vector of strings in `text` `str_match_all(text, "Sent.*?_+(\\d+)")` would return a list of matrices. You need to extract the second column of each matrix. So use `sapply`/`lapply` like `sapply(str_match_all(text, "Sent.*?_+(\\d+)"), function(x) x[, 2])`

Comment: One quick extra question, if I wanted to modify your code to capture numbers without underscores around them, how would I do that? E.g. if after Sent. 1 it was just "1" rather than "________1__________".

Comment: in that case what would be the rule to extract numbers? If we select next number after `"Sent number"` we can do `str_match_all(text, "Sent\\.\\s+\\d+.*?(\\d+).*?\\|")[[1]][, 2]` but it captures some number incorrectly as there are other numbers as well.

Answer (score 2):

library(tidyverse)

```
Data <- c("PASTE YOUR WHOLE STRING")

str_locate(Data, "Sent. ")
Reference <- str_locate_all(Data, "Sent. ") %>% as.data.frame()
Reference %>% names() #Returns [1] "start" "end"  
Reference <- Reference %>% mutate(end = end +1)

YourNumbers <- substr(Data,start = Reference$end[1], stop = Reference$end[1])

for (i in 2:dim(Reference)[1]){
  Temp <- substr(Data,start = Reference$end[i], stop = Reference$end[i])
  YourNumbers <- paste(YourNumbers, Temp, sep = "")
}

YourNumbers #Returns "1234567"
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `strsplit` and `sub`

```
lapply(strsplit(ss, "\\|"), function(x)
    sub("Sent.+: _+(\\d+)_+", "\\1", x[grepl("^Sent", x)]))
#[[1]]
#[1] "1" "3" "1" "1" "5" "3" "1"
```

---

### Sample data

```
ss <- "733|Overall (-2 to 2): _________2________________|How controversial is each sentence (1-5)?|Sent. 1 (ANALYSIS BY...): ________1__________|Sent. 2 (Bail is...): ____3______________|Sent. 3 (2) A...): _______1___________|Sent. 4 (3) A...): _______1___________|Sent. 5 (Proposition 100...): _______5___________|Sent. 6 (In 2006,...): _______3___________|Sent. 7 (That legislation...): ________1__________|Types of bias (check all that apply):|Pro   Anti|X      O   Word use (bold, add alternate)|X      O   Examples (italicize)|O      O   Extra information (underline)|X      O   Any other bias (explain below)|Last sentence makes it sound like an urgent matter.|____________________________________________|NA|undocumented, without a visa|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|"
```